# SQL query - return one result per ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query that will list all servers without a piece of software installed, however the problem is that it is returning more than one Asset ID. 
I want it to just return one result per Asset ID.

I have been trying to use `DISTINCT`, but can't get it right. It is returning thousands rather than a few hundred rows.

Here is the SQL:

```
Select Top 1000000 tblAssets.AssetID,
  tblAssets.AssetUnique,
  tblAssets.Domain,
  tblAssets.Username,
  tblSoftwareUni.softwareName As software,
  tblSoftware.softwareVersion As version,
  tblSoftwareUni.SoftwarePublisher As publisher,
  tsysOS.OSname As OS,
  tsysOS.Image As icon

From tblSoftware
  Inner Join tblAssets On tblSoftware.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
  Inner Join tblSoftwareUni On tblSoftware.softID = tblSoftwareUni.SoftID
  Inner Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
  Inner Join tsysOS On tblAssets.OScode = tsysOS.OScode

Where tblSoftwareUni.softwareName Not Like 'Hawkeye G Host Sensor%' And
  tblAssetCustom.State = 1 
  AND  tsysOS.OSname Not Like 'Win 7' 
  AND tsysOS.OSname Not Like 'Win 10' 
  AND tsysOS.OSname Not Like 'Win 8.1'
  AND tsysOS.OSname Not Like 'Win XP'
  AND tsysOS.OSname Not Like 'Win 8'

Order By AssetID Asc;
```

I have seen similar questions here and tried to implement the suggestions, but can't seem to get it working.

*EDIT*

Apologies for not including this earlier, couldn't format it properly:

Here is a sample of the results that I'm getting:

```
    AssetID AssetUnique Domain  Username    software    version publisher   OS  icon
3133    COMPUTERNAME    DOMAIN  Administrator   Realtek High Definition Audio Driver    5.10.0.5404 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Win 2003 R2 win200310.png
3133    COMPUTERNAME    DOMAIN  Administrator   Certero AssetStudio Client  3.2.0   Certero Win 2003 R2 win200310.png
3133    COMPUTERNAME    DOMAIN  Administrator   Intel(R) PRO Network Connections 12.1.12.0  12.1    Intel   Win 2003 R2 win200310.png
3133    COMPUTERNAME    DOMAIN  Administrator   Certero AssetStudio 5.0 Client  5.0.703.20109   Certero Win 2003 R2 win200310.png
3133    COMPUTERNAME    DOMAIN  Administrator   LiveReg (Symantec Corporation)  2.4.2.2295  Symantec Corporation    Win 2003 R2 win200310.png
3133    COMPUTERNAME    DOMAIN  Administrator   MopUPS Express          Win 2003 R2 win200310.png
3133    COMPUTERNAME    DOMAIN  Administrator   Sophos AutoUpdate   5.2.0.276   Sophos Limited  Win 2003 R2 win200310.png
3133    COMPUTERNAME    DOMAIN  Administrator   MSXML 6 Service Pack 2 (KB954459)   6.20.1099.0 Microsoft Corporation   Win 2003 R2 win200310.png
3133    COMPUTERNAME    DOMAIN  Administrator   Snow Inventory Client for Windows (x86) 3.7.04  Snow Software AB    Win 2003 R2 win200310.png
```

I am getting multiple results per Asset ID, wheras I just want one result.

Comment: Add example data and expected output.

Comment: please post sample data,expected result ,along with what you have tried..please check here to improve the question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Logically your joins are 1:M relationships;   So if `Select distinct top X`... isn't working then, the values you have selected are what's making the record unique and therefor what is causing assetID to be "Duplicated". You could select max() of each value not assetID but is that really the values you want from the other tables?  What determines the value from tsysOS, tblSoftwareUni, tblSoftware for each AssetID?

Comment: Apologies - I have included the results now. I couldn't get the formatting right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
select * from
(
select row_number()over(partition by tblAssets.AssetID order by (select NULL)) Rn,
       ...
from your query
) A
Where RN = 1
```

Replace the `(select NULL)` in `Order by` if you have any other column to order the result and fetch the first or last one.

Now the result will be arbitrary, different records can be selected for each `AssetID`

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER() Function to get the distinct rows per AssetID. Something like....

```
SELECT Top 1000000 * 
FROM (
Select  tblAssets.AssetID,
  tblAssets.AssetUnique,
  tblAssets.Domain,
  tblAssets.Username,
  tblSoftwareUni.softwareName As software,
  tblSoftware.softwareVersion As version,
  tblSoftwareUni.SoftwarePublisher As publisher,
  tsysOS.OSname As OS,
  tsysOS.Image As icon,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  tblAssets.AssetID ORDER BY  tblAssets.AssetID)rn

From tblSoftware
  Inner Join tblAssets On tblSoftware.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
  Inner Join tblSoftwareUni On tblSoftware.softID = tblSoftwareUni.SoftID
  Inner Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
  Inner Join tsysOS On tblAssets.OScode = tsysOS.OScode

Where tblSoftwareUni.softwareName Not Like 'Hawkeye G Host Sensor%' And
  tblAssetCustom.State = 1 
  AND  tsysOS.OSname Not Like 'Win 7' 
  AND tsysOS.OSname Not Like 'Win 10' 
  AND tsysOS.OSname Not Like 'Win 8.1'
  AND tsysOS.OSname Not Like 'Win XP'
  AND tsysOS.OSname Not Like 'Win 8'
 )A
WHERE rn = 1
Order By AssetID Asc
```